# How to get back from "testing" to "stable" - Kernel downgrade

Tags: debian, kernel

currently I am having lot's of fun with `apt-get` - and the bad thing is, it was my own fault. I had enabled the `testing` packages in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to install a certain package. And I told my system do `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Everything worked fine, but now I am trying to get back to the `stable`updated - and I fail...

When trying to do the `apt-get dist-upgrade`, i get the following information:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.10-3-amd64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcgi-fast-perl libfcgi-perl libyaml-syck-perl
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  initramfs-tools libdate-manip-perl munin munin-common
```

Well, that's okay, but when I am try to do this, I get a warning in bold friendly red letters:

```
You are running a kernel (version 3.10-3-amd64) and attempting to remove the same version.
...
It is highly recommended to abort the kernel removal unless you are prepared to fix the system after removal.
```

Well, I like to follow the recommendmend. The correct kernel version for the `stable` release would be `linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64` and it is already installed. Probably the downgrade would be no problem if I was working under the older kernel? Actually, I have no clue how to enable the kernel `3.2.0` instead of `3.10`.

Comment: I hate to break this to you, but downgrades are not supported in Debian. You are not specific about how much of your system now consists of packages from testing (this is discoverable, for example, by apt-show-versions), but if it is a significant part, you may have problems.

The solution to your immediate issue seems simple, unless I am missing something. Just reboot into 3.2 and then remove the newer kernel. However, this won't make the rest of your system magically revert to stable.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I see, there is not so much trouble at all - just a few packages... Is there an option to tell the system to use the kernel 3.2 after reboot? I am working on a VPS (virtual server) and won't be able to click any button before SSH is up...

Comment: You are saying you can't select the kernel interactively at boot? If you are using GRUB, you should be able to go to the grub config and change your default choice of kernel to boot from. The details would depend on what version of GRUB you are running.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: That's it! I just have to find out about my bootloader now (well .. I never saw it). Thanks!

Comment: @Wilf: Well - disabling the `testing` packages just drove me in that situation :) Actually I changed the packages from `squeeze` to `stable` and disabled `testing` in the same step. Therefore, the changes were not so bad, but still confusing enough.

Comment: @Wilf Debian won't automatically attempt a downgrade. You could configure apt to try to do that, but I don't think that would help here.

Comment: Sorry - more of Fedora & Ubuntu user... *(why debian based systems can't have a decent package manager, i don't know :P )* - Anyway, you could try configuring grub to show using `/etc/default/grub` - manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration)

Comment: @Wilf: At the moment, I still try to figure out which bootloader I use. I am working on a VPS and only access the system via SSH - so I cannot see any bootloader at all. However, I am just considering to keep the newer kernel and a few newer packages - probably a working system with few packages "out of the distribution" is better than a non-working (remote) system that is 100% distribution :)

Comment: well, it will likely be Grub, or LILO - check the `/boot` folder. Hopefully it is smart enough to use the 3.2 kernel if the 3.10 doesn't exist.

Comment: You probably are using GRUB. Post your version of GRUB, `dpkg -l | grep grub` in the question.

Answer (score 55):

Look at this, it seems to indicate that downgrade is possible using apt-get:

http://ispire.me/downgrade-from-debian-sid-to-stable-from-jessie-to-wheezy/

Essentials (3-step):
*(If much of your system is of a higher version, you'll want to be careful downgrading. See especially format changes (data and personal config files)*

1. Remove all references to **sid** or **unstable** in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by deleting, replacing, or commenting out. Ensure `sources.list` has what you do want (I recommend security and stable deb sources). For example:

   > deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
   >   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
   >
   > deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
   >   deb-src http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
2. Pin the release you want in `/etc/apt/preferences` (this will cause the already downloaded but now unwanted package information to be ignored as desired).

   > Package: *
   >   Pin: release a=stable
   >   Pin-Priority: 1001
3. Finally we have to run the apt update and upgrade process for downgrading all packages.
   *`apt` will ask for confirmation

   > `# apt-get update`
   >   `# apt-get upgrade`
   >   `# apt-get dist-upgrade`

If you can't explain what each of these commands does independently, **read your man pages!** :) And do the same for at least the options you use in other utilities.

4. *(If you have issues downgrading a package)*
   Purge it, then reinstall

> `# apt-get purge [your_failing_package]`
>   `# apt-get install [your_failing_package]`

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! The core of it is step 2.

Comment: The `/etc/issue` and other files are kept not downgraded. How to resolve it?

Comment: I was able to resolve some issues after the downgrade with `apt-get install --reinstall $pkg` rather than purging then installing.

Answer (score 4):

- Reboot the machine.
- From Debian advanced menu on Grub, choose a kernel different from the
  one you want to remove.
- If you're on Debian you'd have a meta package for the kernel
  installed.

  ```
  gayan@deb:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux 
  ii  linux-image-amd64                     4.9.25-1~bpo8+1
  ii  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64            3.16.43-2
  ii  linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64       4.9.25-1~bpo8+1
  ```
- Simply purge the meta package (`linux-image-amd64`) and and reinstall
  it.

  Then you'd have:

  ```
  gayan@deb:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux
  ii  linux-image-amd64                     3.16.43-2
  ii  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64            3.16.43-2
  ```
- Reboot.

---

**Info:**

`linux-image-amd64` is a meta package. It could point to a either stable kernel or a back-ported one (4.9.25-1~bpo8+1) depending on how you install it:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

or

```
apt-get install linux-image-amd64
```