# Migrating from Debian sid/unstable to testing

Tags: debian, upgrade

I believe there is no official way to do this but I am hoping for a best practices suggestion.

Background: When Debian 9 is rolled out and testing is unfrozen (and therefore becomes v10), I assume lots of packages from unstable will move to testing.  At that point I will want to start using testing again, assuming the packages I need are included.

So the question I have is how can I do this elegantly?

Comment: "At that point I will want to start using testing again". What would you be using previous to that point - unstable?

Comment: Yes, unstable.  I am currently using unstable and want to begin to use testing, once the packages that I need are in testing.

Comment: This might be useful, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153606/152478

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to track the testing distribution, I would strongly recommend running a mixture of testing and unstable: that will allow you to pull in updated packages from unstable if necessary (*e.g.* for security fixes). To do this, ensure both testing (named as such, rather than the specific release name) and unstable are available in your configured repositories; then set up pinning, *e.g.* in `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 200
```

This will result in packages being tracked in testing if they’re available there, unstable if they’re not, or if they’re installed in a version newer than what’s available in testing. As Debian transitions from preparing Stretch to preparing Buster, and packages migrate from unstable to testing, your local installation will progressively start tracking Buster instead of unstable. This avoids needing to downgrade anything, and hopefully should result in a Buster setup in relatively short order after Stretch is released since testing and unstable haven’t yet diverged too much. (This will change *very* quickly after Stretch releases, so make sure you set this up before then.)

This kind of setup avoids issues with packages disappearing from testing for sometimes long periods. It also makes it easy to track security uploads to unstable, using [Paul Wise’s patch to `debsecan`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=725934). I’ve been running this on my main setup for years without issue (but then again, I’m intimately familiar with the inner workings of Debian). The annoyances Fahim mentions in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370113/86440) mostly concern new installations of packages, which can be troublesome in pure testing; in practice they’re not much of an issue on a running system.

The usual caveats to running testing and/or unstable apply. You should make sure you’re familiar with the [best practices](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable#What_are_some_best_practices_for_testing.2Fsid_users.3F). In particular, make sure you’re aware of *all* the changes `apt-get` wants to make on upgrades before letting it loose.

Comment: This sounds like the way to go, but I am concerned that there will be too many packages to pin them all.  Is the asterisk a wildcard, or is it a placeholder?  Meaning: do I have to specify all packages or will the wildcard handle everything?

Comment: I did some research and I wonder what you think about the note from JoshuaRodman on this page: https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences

Comment: The asterisk is a wildcard, you don’t need to specify individual packages (but you can if you want, *e.g.* to pull in a specific package from unstable). Joshua’s note is very old (dating back to Woody), but it’s a useful idea in some circumstances (I do something similar for `non-free`); I wouldn’t use that approach in general myself, but feel free to use it if it makes you feel safer. (The comment about testing depending on unstable is odd though; testing is supposed to be consistent.)

Comment: Great.  Your thoughts on Joshua's comments align with my own.  So this q/a and the debian link (https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) should combine to be a good answer to this question as of June 2017, right before Debian 9 comes out.  Also, I have done this on one of my servers and then upgraded and didn't have any problems, so I guess it's working so far.  Thank you @Stephen Kitt

Comment: I did this back then when you suggested it and it worked great.  Can you remind me/educate me on what to do now that Debian 9 has come out?  I want to get on the fully testing track, and then (in two years or whatever) eventually end up on stable (Debian 10) - thank you.

Comment: If you specify `buster` instead of `testing` you’ll end up on Buster, which is current testing, and when that releases as Debian 10, you’ll stay on it even though it will then be stable. At that point (after the release of Debian 10) you should remove the unstable entries.

Comment: Great.  If I had specified "stretch" instead of "testing" back in June, then would I currently be on Debian 9?  Obviously it's too late for that.  Just trying to make sure I understand.

Comment: follow-up:  If I have not run apt-get upgrade since before Debian 9 became stable, can I still get on the stretch bandwagon or is it too late?

Comment: It depends on what packages and what versions you have installed — in June, quite a few packages were still the same in Stretch and unstable, but some had diverged already. You can check without breaking anything: change to `stretch`, run `apt update`, and then run `apt-show-versions` and check how many packages are not from Stretch. You can then decide whether to stay on Stretch or switch to Buster...

Comment: change what to stretch?  I'm still using that preferences file, so exactly what setting should I change to stretch?

Comment: I was referring to your question: specify “stretch” instead of “testing”.

Comment: Okay.  That's what I figured but wasn't 100% sure.  So I've done that, and I still have "unstable" in there of course.  Now I get an error that "apt-show-versions" command isn't found.  Of course I know how to install a package with debian, but how do I install something now, without definitively choosing buster vs stretch?

Comment: You can install `apt-show-versions`, and you should end up with the Stretch version. You’re not choosing definitively: if you later decide to switch to Buster, you can easily upgrade the package to the Buster version.

Comment: I have installed and run apt-show-versions.  You said to "check how many packages are not from Stretch" but did not say how.  When I run that command, I see a list of packages.  Some say "uptodate" and some day "upgradeable" and some say "No available version in archive".  Does this infer something about how many packages are not from Stretch?

Comment: In `apt-show-versions`’ output, you’ll see what suite a package corresponds to, *e.g.* `adduser:all/stretch 3.115 uptodate` (note the `/stretch` part). That’s what you can use to check for packages which aren’t from Stretch.

Comment: I see what you're saying but what I see is the word "testing" rather than "stretch" but I guess that in this case, testing means stretch?  (I installed the packages when the source was set to "testing" and have changed the line to "stretch" but never to "buster" so I guess "testing" in this case is safe?  (I do have two items that say "unstable": libreadline6 and libunistring0)

Comment: Confirmed on another server.  I guess the specific question I have is if there is a way to make apt-show-versions tell me the version by proper noun rather than "testing"?  (And I am looking at the man page as well of course.)

Comment: BTW this has all worked out for me at this point.  I forgot to mention that.  I'm just trying to fill in the gaps of my knowledge here with the additional questions.  But you have successfully guided me through what I needed to accomplish.  Thank you.

Comment: “testing” means Buster in `apt-show-version`’s output, AFAICS. You can check the versions against the information on [the tracker](https://tracker.debian.org) or using `rmadison` (in the `devscripts` package). I’m glad you got things worked out, you’re welcome :-).

Comment: I hope you're wrong because I did apt-get upgrade.  I think it can't be buster by default, because that would imply that apt-show-version queried a server for the current name of testing.  Seems more likely (to me) that that tag comes from the name that was in sources.list at the time.  Since I had never mentioned buster and had not apt-get update'd since buster became testing, I think (hope!) I'm in the clear and currently have a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

When you're ready to switch to testing, I'd just switch your sources from unstable to testing, or adjust your preferences. You would also need to downgrade the packages that have an unstable version that is higher than the testing version from the unstable version to the testing version. This downgrading may or may not be easy to do, but I don't think that is anything else you can do. A separate question, which you have not asked, is whether this is a good idea. I don't believe it is. because for much of the time till late in the testing cycle (or so I have heard) unstable is actually more reliable than testing.

If you want to ask about whether your procedure is a good idea, you could add that question to your current question, or write a separate question. I think the former would be reasonable.

To downgrade an individual package, the following works to a first approximation

```
apt-get install pkgname/release
```

In the case mentioned here, release=testing. You might need to also force a downgrade for additional packages, depending on the dependencies. You can specify them on the command line as additional arguments, namely

```
apt-get install pkgname1/release pkgname2/release ...
```

Comment: You said "You would also need to downgrade the packages that have an unstable version that is higher than the testing version from the unstable version to the testing version. "  How would you approach that?  Can you edit your answer to say?

Comment: See edit. But this topic is covered in additional questions on this site.

Comment: Can you send those links?  I posted this after searching, and if I didn't find them then someone else might not also.  It's often the case that people who already know the answer can recognize a question as being appropriate, but people who don't know don't realize that there is a connection.

Comment: Hi @stone.212 I added the relevant information to the question as you requested. Doing a search for "debian downgrade packages" gives various hits. Unfortunately, much of this is not useful. The method I've recommended is safe. In particular, I do *NOT* recommend messing with the priorities in `/etc/apt/preferences`, as some people have suggested.

Comment: @Faheem we don’t officially support downgrading ;-). Why don’t you recommend changing priorities?

Comment: Hi @StephenKitt. To be clear, I was talking about changing priorities for the purposes of downgrading. I don't think this is a good way to do unless you're experienced with this kind of thing. And yes, I know Debian doesn't officially support downgrading.

Comment: Ah right @Faheem, that makes sense.

Comment: @Faheem I am glad your comments are in this thread but I'm not going to mark as an official "answer" because it's not officially supported.  Also, you once again glanced over the meat of a comment.  You said "I do NOT recommend messing with the priorities..." but didn't explain why, so I can't say whether what you're saying adds up.  Anyway, thank you and I've messed with /etc/apt/preferences and it *seems* ok?

Comment: @stone.212 It should be obvious why I say "I do NOT recommend messing with the priorities". Because people mess it up. Keep it simple. The approach I described is is much more simple and conservative. And though Debian does not officially support downgrades (for obvious reasons) most of the time they work. I once talked someone successfully through the mass downgrade of multiple Debian (or possibly a DD) machines, including a downgrade of `libc6`. The question and and answer are here somewhere. I assume this was paid work. Unfortunately, I didn't get a cut...

Comment: @Faheem You said " It should be obvious...."  To you, perhaps it is.  But if things like this were obvious, we wouldn't be posting here.  Any further discussion would get into opinions regarding what is simple and not, and opinions are not appropriate in this forum so I'll simply thank you again for taking time to reply.

Comment: To repeat myself again, by messing with `preferences`, I mean in the context of mass downgrades. I already said this to Stephen.