# boot hangs at “Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.”

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia

I upgraded my Debian system from Debian stretch to Debian sid,
which is not a stable version. 
After I finished upgrading, I tried to reboot my system. It hangs at

```
Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes
```

- I searched the internet for solutions. 
  Most of them were about video card problems. 
  I tried every solution, but none of them has worked.
- I also tried to install the `nvidia` driver manually using `.run` file. 
  I get an error saying

  ```
  failed to run /usr/sbin/dkms build
  ```

I am using an nVidia G 210 VGA.

Answer (score 0):

You say that message appears on reboot, but does that mean on startup or shutdown? If it's on shutdown, then hit Alt+SysRq+{R,E,I,S,U,B} (hit Alt+SysRq and tap each of the letters) to perform a reboot and then manually force a downgrade back to stretch.

If your system hangs on startup, you can bypass systemd by booting into a bash shell. On boot, tap `Esc` until the GRUB menu appears, highlight your operating system, press `e` to edit, add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the line starting with `linux`, and press `Ctrl+x` to boot. From there, you can remount root as read-write via `mount -oremount,rw /`, bring network interfaces up via `ip` or `ifconfig`, and downgrade to stretch.

Downgrade instructions are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153606/277591 if you need them.

Comment: i had to downgrade my kernel version so i can install nvidia driver

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem rebooting after upgrading from jessie to stretch. At first, I tried fixing the problem by removing the xserver-xorg-video-intel package, per other solutions reported, but this did not solve my problem.

But I also saw Virtualbox having a problem in theboot sequence before this hang, so I used the jessie install CD to boot into rescue mode with networking, dropped into root on the HD root partition, and:

- apt-get remove virtualbox
- apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms

Then rebooted, and there was no hang.