# Debian: Can't install qtcreator because of broken packages

Tags: debian, apt, qt, mesa

I'm trying to install qtcreator or any other qt development package but it's not working because of broken packages. I then tried to install qtcreator manually from the qt website but I can't compile anything because of this error `cannot find -lGL`.

I then tried installing libgl1-mesa-dev and I get the same error as when installing qtcreator:

```
> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 13.0.6-1+b2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.69) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-dri3-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It may have something to do with my sources.list, I added this:

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
```

And I'm using debian 9.9 stable, I installed some packages using `sudo apt-get -t testing install <package>`

Did I broke my system? Is there a way to fix it or should I reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did I broke my system?

Yes.

> Is there a way to fix it or should I reinstall it?

Yes, remove the testing sources then follow the instruction described on the debian wiki : [System-Downgrade](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemDowngrade) and [How to get back from “testing” to “stable” - Kernel downgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117122/how-to-get-back-from-testing-to-stable-kernel-downgrade)

The `qtcreator` is available on debian stretch, you can install it through:

```
apt install qtcreator
```

Comment: There are still some packages from debian testing I want to use, will they still work after the downgrade? Or should I consider doing a debian testing install?

Comment: @nexide If the package isn't available on debian stretch  it is better to install the testing release.